# How to iterate over a vector of functions and call them without moving the vector?

Tags: rust

I have a struct that contains a vector of functions and a method that iterates over each and calls it.

```
struct App {
    functions: Vec<Box<dyn FnOnce(i32) -> i32>> 
}

impl App {
    pub fn run(&mut self) {
        for function in &mut self.functions {
            println!("{}", (function)(1));
        }
    }
}
```

However, I this moves the vector and I have not found a clean way to copy it.

```
cannot move out of `*function` which is behind a mutable reference
move occurs because `*function` has type `Box<dyn FnOnce(i32) -> i32>`, which does not 
implement the `Copy` trait (rustc E0507)
```

So is there any way to call the function without moving it or a clean way to copy it.

Comment: `FnOnce` functions can only be called once. This requires them to be moved and consumed on execution. You will either have to move the whole vec, move each function from the vec, or switch to `FnMut` or `Fn` instead.

Comment: That restriction is reflected in the [signature of `call_once`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html#tymethod.call_once), which takes `self` by value. As opposed to [`call_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html#tymethod.call_mut) and [`call`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Fn.html#tymethod.call) which take `&mut self` and `&self` respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way function traits in Rust are structured are a little confusing at the beginning, but follow the same pattern of ownership.

There are three function ownership types:

- `FnOnce` - similar to `self`. Requires the caller to own this function object, and the object will be consumed. This is the strongest guarantee a caller can make to a function, and every function is `FnOnce`.
- `FnMut` - similar to `&mut self`. Requires the caller to hold a mutable reference to the function. Can be called multiple times. All the functions that might have side effects require at least `FnMut` ownership. Every function that is executable through an `FnMut` is also compatible with `FnOnce`, as `FnOnce` has stronger ownership guarantees.
- `Fn` - similar to `&self`. Allows the caller to reference this immutably, meaning, this object can be referenced and called from multiple points simultaneously (important: not talking multi-threading here, multi-threading needs `Sync` additionally). This is the weakest ownership requirement, functions that allow owners to call them through this usually have no side effects and just compute an output from an input. All functions that allow being called through `Fn` automatically also can be called through `FnOnce` and `FnMut`, as those give stronger ownership guarantees.

With that out of the way, in your case your functions are `FnOnce`, meaning they require owning. Calling them will consume them. That last part especially is the reason why you get errors here.

The way you own `self` in your `run` method is too weak. You can't call `FnOnce`, which requires ownership, on a `self` object that you don't own. A `&mut self` object only allows you to call `FnMut` members.

So there are two ways to fix your code:

- Change the type of the `self` parameter to owned. Note, however, that this will make `run` a consuming function that will destroy `self` in the end.
- Change the type of your function objects to `FnMut`. This is of course only possible if your functions allow being called through `FnMut`.

---

Here is an example of how it would look like if you changed `FnOnce` to `Fn`:

```rust
struct App {
    functions: Vec<Box<dyn Fn(i32) -> i32>>,
}

impl App {
    pub fn run(&self) {
        for function in &self.functions {
            println!("{}", (function)(1));
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let app = App {
        functions: vec![Box::new(|x| 2 * x), Box::new(|x| 3 * x)],
    };

    app.run();
    app.run();
}
```

```
2
3
```

Note that the closure `|x| 2 * x` here is compatible with `Fn`, because it has zero side effects. This means that our `self` variable can now be an immutable reference, because calling those functions is guaranteed to not mutate `self`.

We can also call `app.run()` multiple times, and `app` doesn't have to be mutable.

---

Now here is an example of a function that requires `FnMut`:

```rust
struct App {
    functions: Vec<Box<dyn FnMut(i32) -> i32>>,
}

impl App {
    pub fn run(&mut self) {
        for function in &mut self.functions {
            println!("{}", (function)(1));
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut add = {
        let mut sum = 0;
        move |x| {
            sum += x;
            println!("sum is now {}!", sum);
            sum
        }
    };

    add(5);
    add(10);

    let mut app = App {
        functions: vec![Box::new(add)],
    };

    app.run();
    app.run();
}
```

```
sum is now 5!
sum is now 15!
sum is now 16!
16
sum is now 17!
17
```

This function now has a side effect - it changes the value of `sum` every time it is called. It is therefore no longer compatible with `Fn`, and using it in the previous code would cause an error.

Our function objects now have to be `FnMut`, our `self` has to become `&mut self` and our `app` object is required to be mutable.

We are, however, still able to call `app.run()` multiple times.

---

Now, lets see what would be necessary to use an `FnOnce`:

```rust
struct App {
    functions: Vec<Box<dyn FnOnce(i32) -> i32>>,
}

impl App {
    pub fn run(self) {
        for function in self.functions {
            println!("{}", (function)(1));
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let add = {
        let s = String::new();
        move |x| {
            drop(s);
            x
        }
    };

    let app = App {
        functions: vec![Box::new(add)],
    };

    app.run();
}
```

```
1
```

The reason this closure is `FnOnce` is because of the `drop`. It destroys the `s` variable when called, and that can for obvious reasons only happen once.

Therefore, to store it in the `App`, `App` has to change its function object type to `FnOnce`. Further, `self` in the `run()` method now also needs to be taken as an owned object, because parts of it will get destroyed in the process.

This now means that we can call `app.run()` only once. There is no need to mark `app` as `mut`, because it won't get mutated in the process, it will get completely consumed, so we don't need to worry about mutability. It simply can't get accessed afterwards any more.

It makes sense that we can now call `app.run()` only once, because the function it contains can also only be called once.

---

I hope this helped somehow to increase your understanding of your situation.