# Is This Explanation I Was Given (Rust Code Behind The Scenes Requires Consumption of Variable Upon Invocation) Correct?

Tags: rust, struct, closures

I was having some trouble understanding closures, so I hopped onto a forum to ask some questions about what went on under the hood. Someone gave me this example:

> For the below code:
>
> ```
> let x = String::new();
> let f = || { println!("{x}") };
> f();
> ```
>
> The below code is generated by Rust behind the scenes (this is just an
> approximation, it does not really run):
>
> ```
> struct UnnameableClosureType<'a> {
>     x0: &'a String,
> }
>
> impl<'a> Fn<()> for UnnameableClosureType<'a> {
>     type Output = ();
>
>     extern "rust-call" fn call(&self, args: Args) -> Self::Output {
>         println!("{}", self.x0);
>     }
> }
>
> impl<'a> FnMut<()> for UnnameableClosureType<'a> {
>     type Output = ();
>
>     extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, args: Args) -> Self::Output {
>         self.call(args)
>     }
> }
>
> impl<'a> FnOnce<()> for UnnameableClosureType<'a> {
>     type Output = ();
>
>     extern "rust-call" fn call_once(mut self, args: Args) -> Self::Output {
>         self.call_mut(args)
>     }
> }
>
> let x = String::new();
> let f = UnnameableClosureType {
>     x0: &x
> };
> f();
> ```
>
> Since this requires consumption of x upon invocation, the only trait
> that can be implemented is FnOnce, and not Fn or FnMut.

That's the explanation I was given.

What I don't really understand is how the compiler knows that FnOnce is the only trait that can be implemented.

I tried suggesting that if the input variable (which was a moved value) got moved to `&self.x0` and then dropped, there would be a dangling reference `&self.x0`, but I'm not really sure if that is correct, and even that sounds a bit weird to me because that describes the outcome that we want to avoid (and even then, I'm not sure if that would actually happen) instead of the rules the compiler uses.

Is the explanation I was given correct, and is my understanding of it sound?

Comment: The explanation looks fine to me. However then you start talking about code you haven't shown us (what is `z`?), so we can't help further  if you don't ask us the complete question with context.

Comment: @JMAA, my mistake, it should have been 'consumption of `x`'. I have edited the question accordingly to reflect that.

Comment: @JMAA, what I don't understand is how requiring the consumption of x upon invocation leads to the compiler knowing that FnOnce is the only trait that can be implemented.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but here's a [post I wrote a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74755016/2902833) about the difference of `Fn`, `FnMut` and `FnOnce`.

Comment: *"Since this requires consumption of x upon invocation, the only trait that can be implemented is FnOnce, and not Fn or FnMut."* - This sentence is wrong. The closure in the example does not capture `x`, it only captures `&x`. Further, it does not drop `x`. It is therefore compatible with all three of those traits, as seen [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3291c62b7f2c5df0e90a4e2750652aff). Note even if it were to capture `x` by adding the `move` keyword, it would still implement all three of those, as it has no side effects.

Comment: @Finomnis, ok... this LEGIT answered my question. If you just copy-pasted it as an answer, I would mark it as 'answer' without further questions asked. 
Also, I just tried `fn apply_to_closure<F>(mut f:F)` without defining the closure variable as 'let mut f' ..., and it worked just fine. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What I don't really understand is how the compiler knows that FnOnce is the only trait that can be implemented.

That's because it doesn't. The explanation is wrong; the given closure implements all three of them; `Fn`, `FnMut` and `FnOnce`.

I'm not sure about the exact code the compiler generates, but here's the principle behind it:

- By default, every closure implements `Fn`, `FnMut` and `FnOnce`, unless something prevents that. Example:

  ```rust
  // Fn + FnMut + FnOnce
  let f = |x| 2*x;
  ```
- If a closure performs an action that requires `&mut`, it will no longer implement `Fn`, because `Fn` can only perform immutable actions. Example:

  ```rust
  let mut sum = 0;
  // FnMut + FnOnce
  let f = |x| sum += x;
  ```
- If a closure performs an action that requires taking ownership of something, it will no longer implement `FnMut` or `Fn`, because both of those do not allow consuming things. Example:

  ```rust
  let s = String::new();
  // Only FnOnce, because `drop` consumes `s`
  let f = || drop(s);
  ```

Further, be aware that whether or not a closure is `move` or not does not influence which of those traits it implements. What **does** determine these traits is how it uses those captures - for example, if it calls a `&mut self` function of such a captured object, that would remove the `Fn` trait, because `Fn` closures cannote mutate things.